# csr_matrix row indexing is much slower than dense array?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I created a huge sparse matrix in `csr` format, and for some reason, I need to iterate through the rows (randomly) and to `dot` operations, and I found the code is much much slower than using dense array, here is the benchmark.

```
In [1]: a = sp.csr_matrix(np.random.rand(10000, 10000))
In [2]: b = a.todense()

In [126]: %timeit a[1357]
10000 loops, best of 3: 78.1 µs per loop

In [127]: %timeit b[1357]
The slowest run took 6.80 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.49 µs per loop
```

dense array row indexing is about 30x faster than `csr_matrix`, am I doing this right, and how to improve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why is row indexing of scipy csr matrices slower compared to numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010334/why-is-row-indexing-of-scipy-csr-matrices-slower-compared-to-numpy-arrays)

Comment: @sascha yes, could be a dup,and I indeed read that one, but that answer just explained why it's slow, I didn't see (anything I missed?) any solution to improve the speed.

Comment: In regards to this question: it's too broad (depends very much on the use-case) or do you think it's slow because it's wanted? :-)

Comment: The dense selection returns a `view`.  The sparse selection creates a new sparse matrix with new attributes.  But why do a dot product on rows individually?  Try to work with whole matrix without iteration.

Comment: @hpaulj, actually doing a mini-batch iterative algo, so

Comment: When selecting multiple rows, `sparse` uses matrix multiplication - with an appropriate 'extractor' matrix.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500649/sparse-matrix-slicing-using-list-of-int

Comment: @hpaulj, however, if I access the `.data` via `.indptr`, it's much much faster, so I'm thinking maybe get data from sparse array that way, and do a elem-wise product and sum it all, instead of doing sparse matrix row indexing and dot product.

Comment: @avocado where you able to solve the problem? Care to please share your solution? I am coding an Stochastic Gradient Descent method and I am going through the rows randomly and it would be helpful to know what you did in the end. Thanks